# Deprecated APIs should be marked accordingly in the Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

### Feature Request

Today it is possible to version APIs and most things around that work perfectly fine with Swagger. What I am really missing here is the possibility to make it transparent for any Swagger UI users that an API **version** has been marked as deprecated.

API deprecation in aspnetcore is described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Deprecating-a-Service-Version).
My expectation would be to have an icon or a tag which says "OBSOLETE" or "DEPRECATED" next to the API group name.

###### On a side note:

The Swashbuckle Swagger ASPNET.Core github project issue tracker advised to open feature requests on SO.

Edit:

The whole Controller is marked as deprecated using the ApiVersion attribute. If you mark the controller as [Obsolete] all the methods are grey and text is striked through. However this is not what I am looking for. I don't want mark my codebase [Obsolete]. I want to mark a specific API version as deprecated so people know they should switch to a newer version.

```cs
   [ApiVersion("1", Deprecated = true)]
   [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
   [Authorize("my.auth.policy")]
   [ApiController]
   public class MyApiController
   {
      // do stuff
   }
```

My current workaround is this:
In my Startup I add the swaggerUI and do a custom formatting on the swagger endpoint dropdown display.

```cs
app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                foreach (ApiVersionDescription apiVersionDescription in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(a => a.ApiVersion))
                {
                    string isDeprecated = apiVersionDescription.IsDeprecated ? " (DEPRECATED)" : string.Empty;
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{Configuration["PathBase"]}/swagger/{apiVersionDescription.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                        $"{apiVersionDescription.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()}{isDeprecated}");
                }
            });
```

[image: Swagger UI API definition dropdown]

Comment: OpenAPI Specification has the [`deprecated`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/#deprecated) attribute for operations, and Swagger UI displays deprecated operations in gray color - see, for example, `GET /pets/fingByTags` here: https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/findPetsByTags. Does Swashbuckle have an annotation that translates to OpenAPI `deprecated` attribute? On an unrelated note, Stack Overflow is not a place for 3rd-party feature requests, such requests belong to the project's repository / issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

@helen

#### Definition

```cs
public class CustomHeaderFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        var apiDescription = context.ApiDescription;
        if (apiDescription.IsDeprecated())
        {
            operation.Deprecated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Use

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(g =>
{
    g.OperationFilter<CustomHeaderFilter>();
}).AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

#### The interface must have the following

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = true)]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

#### result

[image]